# DateTime ParseException for date with offset

Tags: java, date, datetime

How do I parse a date string like `2014-04-25T01:50:00.000-06:00`? I am using Joda DateTime and have tried something like:

```
public static String formatDate(Date d){
    SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.00'0Z'");
    String mdy = mdyFormat.format(d);
    return mdy;
}
```

However, the result is an error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2014-04-25T01:50:00.000-06:00"

Comment: Try: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: Hey Larme, I have tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: Why is your question "how to **parse**", but your code is about **formatting** a `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the format in this way:

```
 DateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use old JDK-`SimpleDateFormat` try this Java7-pattern:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Reason is given in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone:
>                Sign TwoDigitHours  : Minutes

If you use JodaTime you should not use `SimpleDateFormat` but a [Joda-solution](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern%28java.lang.String%29) otherwise you will only mix JDK- and Joda types in a confusing way:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

**UPDATE because of your comment on Jespers answer:**

If you just want to convert a `DateTime` to `java.util.Date` then this is neither a formatting nor a parsing issue. The solution is much simpler. Just use [toDate()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29):

```
DateTime dt = ...;
java.util.Date jdkDate = dt.toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's standard ISO 8601 format. If you're using Joda Time:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
DateTime dateTime = fmt.parseDateTime("2014-04-25T01:50:00.000-06:00");

// Convert it to java.util.Date
Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jesper, it will be useful to me in future. However my current problem it that I need to convert DateTime to java.util.Date, and when I try to parse the value into Date I get this exception.

Comment: Converting a Joda `DateTime` to a `java.util.Date` is very simple; you just call `toDate()` on it. I'll update my answer.